# Standard function to throw an exception if an expression is false?

Tags: dart

The assert statement method only works in development.  Is there a standard Dart function which works like assert but which will be executed when running production code?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
void myFunc(List myList) {
  validate(myList.isNotEmpty);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Check this link dude! I do not use this but I think it may help you. https://pub.dev/packages/angel_validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the Dart SDK, but Google's [quiver package](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver) provides a [`checkState`](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.check/checkState.html) function that does what you want.